# Is there a batch command to copy from dir A to dir B, but backs up files in dir B that are going to be overwritten to dir C first?

Tags: file, backup, patch

Basically,

I need to apply a manual patch to a program with a zip of patch files.

There is a chance this patch will break things, but without the patch, the program works at the moment.

There has to be a way to back up what's to be overwritten by the patch files.

I just don't know what it is and this has been a tough questions to find answer for on the web.

```
# Python - This is not real code, just the idea

Dir_A = os.walk(.\A)
Dir_B = os.walk(.\B)
Dir_C = .\C

ListOfBackup = [file for file in Dir_B if file in Dir_A]

Copy(ListOfBackup, Dir_C)
```

This is such a simple but also intricate task that I feel like whipping out a Python script to do it might not be the best idea.  Using an actual program to do it is also taking a gun to a knife fight.

The dilemmas...

Robocopy might be the best choice but I have not being able to make it work.

I wonder if any one has done it with windows batch/powershell?

I'm expecting that this task should be doable with Windows Commandline or Powershell instead of using a 3rd party option.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to apply a manual patch to a program with a zip of patch files.
>
> There is a chance this patch will break things, but without the patch,
> the program works at the moment.
>
> There has to be a way to back up what's to be overwritten by the patch
> files.

Sure, many ways.  But before going forward with what you seem to have in mind -- backing up *only* the files that are to be modified -- you should consider backing up *all* the files of the application.  That will probably be easier to do, and it will almost certainly be easier to recover from if that turns out to be needed.  You can do this interactively from the file browser with `[Ctrl]+drag&drop`, or from a shell (PowerShell or cmd.exe) via the standard [`xcopy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/xcopy) command.

Some other alternatives depend on exactly what you mean by "patch".  It's less likely on Windows, but if yours are Unix-style patch files intended to be applied via the Unix [`patch`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) command, then that command has a built-in mechanism for making backup files. Similar is might be true of other patching systems.

Or with Unix-style patches, the patches themselves are a backup of sorts, as they can be applied in the reverse sense to restore the original files from their patched versions.

Comment: This might be the nudge I needed to finally start using Linux.

But yea, the reason I'm not backing up the whole program, is because it is going to waste a ton of space on my drives.  The patch is only a few hundred MB, while the entire application is 50 GB.

It's a game being modded, so it's not that big of a deal if the thing ends up failing.  I'm just aiming to learn a trick or two to save myself time and hard drive space.

Maybe I should use GIT...

Comment: @TeaCrab, it's still not clear to me exactly what you mean by "patch", but if you're talking about running a third-party program that modifies your game in ways you don't *completely* understand, then backing up the whole thing in advance is the only approach I can recommend.

Comment: What I meant by "Patch", is that I have these files structured in a way that I can directly copy and paste into the directory of the application, replacing existing files in that application, to "patch" it.

Well, I understand enough to know that the files that aren't being overwritten shouldn't need to be backed up unless files are generated by the application that ends up being very version-sensitive.

I think I agree with you on the fact that backing up the whole thing might be the best approach, and thank you for bringing it up.

I'm still going to investigate the other approach.

Comment: @TeaCrab do as you think best, of course.  But don't overlook another consideration: what the game might do when you run it after applying the update.  If there's any chance that it may modify any of the files not otherwise updated in a way that depends on files that *were* updated, then you may need backups of those files, too, in order to back out the update.